# How to convert nested dictionary into json object - Odoo12?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to return a nested dictinary as json object but i am getting below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
>       execute(self.server.app)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
>       application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
>     File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_12_EE/odoo/service/server.py", line 409, in app
>       return self.app(e, s)
>     File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_12_EE/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 128, in application
>       return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
>     File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_12_EE/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
>       result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
>     File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_12_EE/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in **call**
>       return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
>     File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_12_EE/odoo/http.py", line 1291, in **call**
>       return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in **call**
>       return self.app(environ, start_response)
>     File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_12_EE/odoo/http.py", line 1491, in dispatch
>       return response(environ, start_response)
>   TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable - - -

Here is my code.
**controller.py**

```
  class GetOrderStatus(http.Controller):
      @http.route('/getOrderStatus/<string:order_num>',type="http",method=['POST','GET'],website=False,auth="public")
      def _get_order_status(self,**kw):
          print('kwww',kw)
          order_id = request.env['helpdesk.ticket'].sudo().search([('name','=',kw.get('order_num'))])
          order_id.ensure_one()
          vals = {
          "statusCode":200,
          "statuDescription":"success",
          "data":{"order_status":order_id.stage_id.name}
          }
          print('vals',vals)
          n = json.dumps(vals)
          return json.loads(n)
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Try to make a response, `return http.request.make_response(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send json data along with your response then make it json type request.

```
from odoo.http import Response
import json
    class GetOrderStatus(http.Controller):
          @http.route('/getOrderStatus/<string:order_num>', type="json", method=['POST','GET'], website=False, auth="public", csrf=False)
          def _get_order_status(self,**kw):
              order_id = request.env['helpdesk.ticket'].sudo().search([('name','=',kw.get('order_num'))])
              order_id.ensure_one()
              return Response(json.dumps({"order_status":order_id.stage_id.name}),content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8',status=200)
```